# Match two objects by key and return a new object with key and value from one object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two objects:

**Object 1**

```
{
  Manufacturer: 'Manufacturer Name',
  User_Name: 'HCP First Name',
  HCP_Middle_Name: 'HCP Middle Name',
  HCP_Last_Name: 'HCP Last Name',
  HCP_NPI: 'HCP NPI',
  HCP_Credentials: 'HCP Credentials',
  HCP_State_License_Number: 'HCP State License Number',
  HCP_State_of_Licensure: 'HCP State of Licensure',
  HCP_Specialty: 'HCP Specialty',
  Teaching_Hospital_Name: 'Teaching Hospital Name',
  Teaching_Hospital_Tax_ID: 'Teaching Hospital Tax ID',
  Address_1: 'Address 1',
  Address_2: 'Address 2',
  City: 'City',
  State: 'State',
  Province: 'Province',
  Postal_Code: 'Postal Code',
  Country: 'Country',
  Spend_Date: 'Spend Date',
  Spend_Currency: 'Spend Currency',
  Spend_Amount: 'Spend Amount',
  Form_of_Payment: 'Form of Payment',
  Nature_of_Payment: 'Nature of Payment',
  Home_System_Identifier: 'Home System Identifier',
  Product_Name: 'Product Name',
  Travel_City: 'Travel City',
  Travel_State: 'Travel State',
  Travel_Country: 'Travel Country'
}
```

**Object 2**

```
[
  {
    Manufacturer: 'Ascendis',
    User_Name: '',
    HCP_Middle_Name: '',
    HCP_Last_Name: '',
    HCP_NPI: '',
    HCP_Credentials: '',
    HCP_State_License_Number: '',
    HCP_State_of_Licensure: '',
    HCP_Specialty: '',
    Teaching_Hospital_Name: '',
    Teaching_Hospital_Tax_ID: '',
    Address_1: '',
    Address_2: '',
    City: '',
    State: '',
    Province: '',
    Postal_Code: '',
    Country: '',
    Spend_Date: '',
    Spend_Currency: '',
    Spend_Amount: '',
    Form_of_Payment: '',
    Nature_of_Payment: '',
    Home_System_Identifier: '',
    Product_Name: '',
    Travel_City: '',
    Travel_State: '',
    Travel_Country: ''
  },
  {
    Manufacturer: 'Amneal',
    User_Name: '',
    HCP_Middle_Name: '',
    HCP_Last_Name: '',
    HCP_NPI: '',
    HCP_Credentials: '',
    HCP_State_License_Number: '',
    HCP_State_of_Licensure: '',
    HCP_Specialty: '',
    Teaching_Hospital_Name: '',
    Teaching_Hospital_Tax_ID: '',
    Address_1: '',
    Address_2: '',
    City: '',
    State: '',
    Province: '',
    Postal_Code: '',
    Country: '',
    Spend_Date: '',
    Spend_Currency: '',
    Spend_Amount: '',
    Form_of_Payment: '',
    Nature_of_Payment: '',
    Home_System_Identifier: '',
    Product_Name: '',
    Travel_City: '',
    Travel_State: '',
    Travel_Country: ''
  }
]
```

What am I trying to accomplish here is to return a new array of objects by comparing the keys and values in **Object 1** with the keys in **Object 2**. For example, In **Object 1**, key "Manufacturer" has a value of "Manufacturer Name", so I need to check in **Object 2** if the key "Manufacturer" exists and if it does, I need to replace the key of "Manufacturer" in **Object 2** with the value in **Object 1** (Manufacturer Name).

Please excuse most of the empty values in Object 2 as these are blank for testing purposes, however, the user will need to populate these in prod.

Comment: No, it does not. The post you linked only shows how to match two object by their key, but does not address all my needs above.

Comment: Something like this: Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key1 => {if (Object.keys(obj2).inclues(key1)) { obj2[obj1[key1]] = obj2[key1]; delete obj2[key1];  }})

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, however, this doesn't work.

Comment: Typo, try this Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key1 => {if (Object.keys(obj2).includes(key1)) { obj2[obj1[key1]] = obj2[key1]; delete obj2[key1]; }})

Comment: It doesn't appear to work. The end result should all keys in Object 2 being replaced by all values in Object 1.

Comment: I get obj2 = { Manufacturer Name: 'Ascendis', HCP First Name: '', HCP Middle Name: '', HCP Last Name: '' ... } which seems fine to me. Are you running it on a specific object in the array or the entire array? You need to give it one object at a time.

Comment: Interesting that is exactly what I'm looking for. Can you link the full code including your console.log statement so I can compare with mine? Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/umeLczjy/

Comment: I was not running my initial code in a for loop. With the for loop, the code works as expected with multiple objects. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key1 => {if (Object.keys(obj2).includes(key1)) { obj2[obj1[key1]] = obj2[key1]; delete obj2[key1]; }})
```